# ef generic set possible bug?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I currently use a generic set of X type where the type is one of the entities generated threw EF. To get my generic set to get data i do this

```
var entityData = db_entities.Set(EntityType);
```

Now i am running a simple check that counts how many elements are in the set and if it's equal to 0 (for example) it will do something (throw exception, redirect, etc..). the problem is when i count how many elements are in the list it goes as follow (using below code)

```
if (entityData.Local.Count == 0) { }
```

when i debug to see what's exactly happening `Local` doesn't have any of the values when i expand the `results view` it shows 11 data (for example) and as i see that the `Local` refreshes and shows the data. i am wondering if am either doing something wrong or it's a bug.

**Edit** 
I changed the logic as it doesn't work by using this, in hopes of an answer or another way

```
var countItems = 0; 

        foreach (var item in entityData)
        {
            //this was added due to a bug when counting the dbSet items
            //will exist after looping first item
            countItems++;
            break;
        }

        if (countItems == 0) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbSet.Local` contains the entities that are already loaded. So when you create a `Set` and then read `Local.Count` it has to be `0`, because nothing was loaded yet.

In the debug view, when expanding the results, the data are loaded from the database and, hence, `Local` now contains entities too.

You can load the `Set` by:

```
var entityData = db_entities.Set(EntityType);
entityData.Load();
```

Now you'll see that `Local.Count` show the actual number of items in the database.